# Neo4j and Cypher: Match nodes that have a single relationship to a target node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to identify nodes that have only one relationship of a given type.

Imagine a graph of Route and Stop nodes. A Route may have 0 or more Stops, a Stop may be shared between multiple Routes, a Stop must always have at least 1 Route. I want to match and delete Stops that will be orphaned if a given Route is deleted.

Before anyone says anything, I know that it would be easier to just find stops without routes after the route is deleted, but that isn't an option. We're also not worried about deleting the routes here, just the stops.

Here's my query:

```
MATCH (r1:Route { id: {route_id} })-[rel1:HAS_STOP]->(s:Stop)
MATCH (r2:Route)-[rel2:HAS_STOP]->(s)
WITH s, COUNT(rel2) as c
WHERE c = 1
MATCH s-[rel2]-()
DELETE s, rel2
```

This works perfectly... but is there a better way? It feels like it could be more efficient but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Here a query that matches only the nodes that will be orphaned without deleting the current route :

```
MATCH (route:Route {id:'99e08bdf-130f-3fca-8292-27d616fa025f'})
WITH route
OPTIONAL MATCH (route)-[r:HAS_STOP]->(s)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((route)--(s)<-[:HAS_STOP]-())
DELETE r,s
```

and the execution plan :

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ PROFILE MATCH (route:Route {id:'99e08bdf-130f-3fca-8292-27d616fa025f'})
> WITH route
> OPTIONAL MATCH (route)-[r:HAS_STOP]->(s)
> WHERE NOT EXISTS((route)--(s)<-[:HAS_STOP]-())
> DELETE r,s;
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 2
Relationships deleted: 2

EmptyResult
  |
  +UpdateGraph
    |
    +Eager
      |
      +OptionalMatch
        |
        +SchemaIndex(1)
        |
        +Filter
           |
           +SimplePatternMatcher
             |
             +SchemaIndex(1)

+----------------------+------+--------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|             Operator | Rows | DbHits |  Identifiers |                                                                                              Other |
+----------------------+------+--------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          EmptyResult |    0 |      0 |              |                                                                                                    |
|          UpdateGraph |    2 |      4 |              |                                                                         DeleteEntity; DeleteEntity |
|                Eager |    2 |      0 |              |                                                                                                    |
|        OptionalMatch |    2 |      0 |              |                                                                                                    |
|       SchemaIndex(1) |    1 |      2 | route, route |                                                                        {  AUTOSTRING0}; :Route(id) |
|               Filter |    2 |      0 |              | NOT(nonEmpty(PathExpression((route)-[  UNNAMED140]-(s),(160)-[  UNNAMED145:HAS_STOP]->(s), true))) |
| SimplePatternMatcher |    2 |      0 |  route, s, r |                                                                                                    |
|       SchemaIndex(1) |    1 |      2 | route, route |                                                                        {  AUTOSTRING0}; :Route(id) |
+----------------------+------+--------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 8
```

** OLD ANSWER **

I let it here for helping maybe others :

In your query, you're not deleting the route nor the relationships to the stops that will not be orphaned. You can do all in one go.

This is what I have as query for the same use case than you, I also compared the two execution plans on a test graph, each route has about 160 stops and 2 stops that will be orphaned after the route deletion, the graph is available here : http://graphgen.neoxygen.io/?graph=JPnvQWZcQW685m

**My query :**

```
MATCH (route:Route {id:'e70ea0d4-03e2-3ca4-afc0-dfdc1754868e'})
WITH route
MATCH (route)-[r:HAS_STOP]->(s)
WITH r, collect(s) as stops
DELETE r, route
WITH filter(x in stops WHERE NOT x--()) as orphans
UNWIND orphans as orphan
DELETE orphan
```

Here is my profiled query :

```
       neo4j-sh (?)$ PROFILE MATCH (route:Route {id:'1c565ac4-b72b-37c3-be7f-a38f2a7f66a8'})
> WITH route
> MATCH (route)-[r:HAS_STOP]->(s)
> WITH route, r, collect(s) as stops
> DELETE r, route
> WITH filter(x in stops WHERE NOT x--()) as orphans
> UNWIND orphans as orphan
> DELETE orphan;
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 2
Relationships deleted: 157

EmptyResult
  |
  +UpdateGraph(0)
    |
    +UNWIND
      |
      +ColumnFilter(0)
        |
        +Eager
          |
          +Extract
            |
            +UpdateGraph(1)
              |
              +ColumnFilter(1)
                |
                +EagerAggregation
                  |
                  +SimplePatternMatcher
                    |
                    +SchemaIndex

+----------------------+------+--------+--------------+------------------------------+
|             Operator | Rows | DbHits |  Identifiers |                        Other |
+----------------------+------+--------+--------------+------------------------------+
|          EmptyResult |    0 |      0 |              |                              |
|       UpdateGraph(0) |    1 |      1 |              |                 DeleteEntity |
|               UNWIND |    1 |      0 |              |                              |
|      ColumnFilter(0) |  157 |      0 |              |         keep columns orphans |
|                Eager |  157 |      0 |              |                              |
|              Extract |  157 |      0 |              |                      orphans |
|       UpdateGraph(1) |  157 |    158 |              |   DeleteEntity; DeleteEntity |
|      ColumnFilter(1) |  157 |      0 |              | keep columns route, r, stops |
|     EagerAggregation |  157 |      0 |              |                     route, r |
| SimplePatternMatcher |  157 |      0 |  route, s, r |                              |
|          SchemaIndex |    1 |      2 | route, route |  {  AUTOSTRING0}; :Route(id) |
+----------------------+------+--------+--------------+------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 161
```

**With your query :**

I slightly modified your query to make use of schema indexes

And this is the Execution plan with your query, the difference in db accesses is quite high

```
PROFILE MATCH (r1:Route { id: '1c565ac4-b72b-37c3-be7f-a38f2a7f66a8' })
> WITH r1
> MATCH (r1)-[rel1:HAS_STOP]->(s:Stop)
> MATCH (r2:Route)-[rel2:HAS_STOP]->(s)
> WITH s, COUNT(rel2) as c
> WHERE c = 1
> MATCH s-[rel2]-()
> DELETE s, rel2;
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 1
Relationships deleted: 1

EmptyResult
  |
  +UpdateGraph
    |
    +Eager
      |
      +SimplePatternMatcher(0)
        |
        +Filter(0)
          |
          +ColumnFilter
            |
            +EagerAggregation
              |
              +Filter(1)
                |
                +SimplePatternMatcher(1)
                  |
                  +Filter(2)
                    |
                    +SimplePatternMatcher(2)
                      |
                      +SchemaIndex

+-------------------------+------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
|                Operator | Rows | DbHits |           Identifiers |                       Other |
+-------------------------+------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
|             EmptyResult |    0 |      0 |                       |                             |
|             UpdateGraph |    1 |      2 |                       |  DeleteEntity; DeleteEntity |
|                   Eager |    1 |      0 |                       |                             |
| SimplePatternMatcher(0) |    1 |      0 |   UNNAMED200, s, rel2 |                             |
|               Filter(0) |    1 |      0 |                       |           c == {  AUTOINT1} |
|            ColumnFilter |  157 |      0 |                       |           keep columns s, c |
|        EagerAggregation |  157 |      0 |                       |                           s |
|               Filter(1) | 4797 |   4797 |                       |       hasLabel(r2:Route(4)) |
| SimplePatternMatcher(1) | 4797 |   4797 |           r2, s, rel2 |                             |
|               Filter(2) |  157 |    157 |                       |         hasLabel(s:Stop(3)) |
| SimplePatternMatcher(2) |  157 |    157 |           r1, s, rel1 |                             |
|             SchemaIndex |    1 |      2 |                r1, r1 | {  AUTOSTRING0}; :Route(id) |
+-------------------------+------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+

Total database accesses: 9912
```

Comment: Really interesting, thanks! I mentioned in the post that I need to only delete the stops and not the route, though. This is used as part of a `before_destroy` callback, so the Route needs to be persisted until the very end since there may be other queries like this to run against it.

Comment: ha ok, didn't catched it up :)

Comment: Very cool, thank you! Much simpler. Early benchmarks indicate yours is indeed faster, as expected. :-) Now to figure out the best way to do it from within the gem. This will be a cool feature when it's done.